# Dynamic position array (K) for Large Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data table of job position and the wage rate based on experience.

My calculation table projects maximum salary expenses by department (job position) but each department have different number of staff on duty.

My data table currently has:

```
Column 1 = job position
Column 2 = years with the company
Column 3 = wage rate (higher with more years)
```

The summary table currently has

```
Column 1 = department (job position)
Column 2 = number of staff on duty per day
Column 3 = maximum wage expenses (filling the shifts with most senior employees)
```

my current formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((job description = department)*wage rate, number of staff on duty))
```

the number of staff on duty is currently entered manually, so if the value in column 2 of the summary table is 4, I enter {1,2,3,4} for K.

I'm wondering if I can make the values change automatically based on the value in column 2 of the summary table, so that if staffing requirement changes from 4 per day to 6, all I would have to do is manually change column 2, and the K array in the LARGE function would update automatically.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on one's version you can either use:

```
SEQUENCE(number of staff on duty)
```

Or

```
ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,number of staff on duty))
```